# pandas: finding first incidences of events in df based on column values and marking as new column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
customer_id event_date data 
1           2012-10-18    0      
1           2012-10-12    0      
1           2015-10-12    0      
2           2012-09-02    0      
2           2013-09-12    1      
3           2010-10-21    0      
3           2013-11-08    0      
3           2013-12-07    1     
3           2015-09-12    1
```

I wish to add additional columns, such as 'flag_1' & 'flag_2' below, which allow myself (and other when I pass on the amended data) to filter easily.

Flag_1 is an indication of the first appearance of that customer in the data set. I have implemented this successfully by sorting:
`dta.sort_values(['customer_id','event_date'])`
and then using: `dta.duplicated(['customer_id']).astype(int)`

Flag_2 would be an indication of the first incidence of each customer when the column 'data' = 1.

An example of what the additional columns implemented would look like below:

```
customer_id event_date data flag_1 flag_2
1           2012-10-18    0      1      0
1           2012-10-12    0      0      0
1           2015-10-12    0      0      0
2           2012-09-02    0      1      0
2           2013-09-12    1      0      1
3           2010-10-21    0      1      0
3           2013-11-08    0      0      0
3           2013-12-07    1      0      1
3           2015-09-12    1      0      0
```

I am new to pandas and unsure how to implement the 'flag_2' column without iterating over the entire dataframe - I  presume there is a quicker way to implement using inbuilt function but haven't found any posts?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First initialize empty flags.  Use `groupby` to get the groups based on the `customer_id`.  For the first flag, use `loc` to set the value of `flag1` for the first value in each group.  Use the same strategy for `flag2`, but first filter for cases where `data` has been set to one.

```
# Initialize empty flags
df['flag1'] = 0
df['flag2'] = 0

# Set flag1
groups = df.groupby('customer_id').groups
df.loc[[values[0] for values in groups.values()], 'flag1'] = 1

# Set flag2
groups2 = df.loc[df.data == 1, :].groupby('customer_id').groups
df.loc[[values[0] for values in groups2.values()], 'flag2'] = 1

>>> df
   customer_id  event_date  data  flag1  flag2
0            1  2012-10-18     0      1      0
1            1  2012-10-12     0      0      0
2            1  2015-10-12     0      0      0
3            2  2012-09-02     0      1      0
4            2  2013-09-12     1      0      1
5            3  2010-10-21     0      1      0
6            3  2013-11-08     0      0      0
7            3  2013-12-07     1      0      1
8            3  2015-09-12     1      0      0
```

Comment: I've tried implementing your solution on my dataset, however the number of 'flag1' values does not appear to be correct (upon checking using `df.customer_id.unique().shape` ).

It appears the list created using `[values[0] for values in groups.values()]` is of correct length and so I presume it must be something to do with the df.loc assignment?

i've also tried using: `df.iloc[[values[0] for values in groups.values()], df.columns.get_loc('flag1')] = 1 ` which does not seem to give correct values in 'flag1' assignment either.

Comment: It appears `df.iloc[[values[0] for values in groups.values()], df.columns.get_loc('flag1')]` identifies the correct df entries for assignment (when using `=1`). But on addition of the `=1` a different row selection is given the value 1. Is this a pandas bug perhaps? i'm using v. 0.17.0

Comment: Can you replicate my results above?

Comment: I replicated your results and have now managed to implement successfully on my own dataset. In the end I had to reset the index prior to implementing in order for it to assign correctly.
`dta = dta.sort_values(['patient_id','admission_datetime'])`
`dta = dta.reset_index(drop=True)`


Many thanks @Alexander